# How can i read bar code from my bar code reader

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-scanner

i just got a bar code reader :
[Barcode Reader](http://www.univers-discount.fr/sf/index.html?lang=fr&target=d235.cfm&lmd=39003.623333)

how can i read the data from this gadget with C# ?

Comment: this might help http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/BarCodeScannerReader.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Typically, barcode readers work as a standard keyboard.

When you scan a barcode, the appropriate information will be "typed" just as if it were a keyboard entry.  You just need to author your software to handle the entry information as normal key data.

Answer (score 3):

A barcode scanner can operate in two modes

- as Reed says like a keyboard
- or as a serial device.

To get it into the latter you will need to 'program' the device (most likely using a special barcode in the manual) and connect to it using `SerialPort`. For example:

```
void setup()
{
    scannerSerialPort = new SerialPort("com1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    if (!scannerSerialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        scannerSerialPort.Open();
        scannerSerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(scannerSerialPort_DataReceived);
    }
}

void scannerSerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        scan += scannerSerialPort.ReadExisting();
        if (scan.EndsWith("\r\n")) {
            scan = scan.Substring(0, scan.Length - 2);
            //act on new value
            UpdateDisplay(scan);
            scan = "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Reed stated, most barcode readers can be configured for "keyboard emulation". However, if you need more control, look into whether the vendor supplies an OPOS driver. Then you can utilize the OPOS common controls from here:

http://monroecs.com/posfordotnet/opos_dotnet.htm