# Not able to read barcode with c# or getting unknown characters

Tags: c#, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am getting error

> `System.TimeoutException was unhandled The operation has timed out... etc`

while I am trying to read a barcode I tried a lot to solve it with but nothing worked out.

I checked parameters of SerialPort that matching Windows Device Manager many times.

I tried to replace

```
String data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
```

with

```
String data = _serialPort.ReadByte().ToString();
```

as you can see, but that show me unknown number it shows for example 12 then removed then 26 etc.

I tried to change the Encoding but when I change the encoding I am getting unknown characters, like empty squares  black triangle  or Playing card symbol etc.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    static SerialPort _serialPort;
    private delegate void SetTextDeleg(string text);

    private void Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
        // Encoding
        //_serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
        _serialPort.Encoding = Encoding.Default;

        _serialPort.Open();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
                _serialPort.Open();

            _serialPort.Write("SI\r\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error opening/writing to serial port :: " + ex.Message, "Error!");
        }
    }

    void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        String data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
        //String data = _serialPort.ReadByte().ToString();
        this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(si_DataReceived), new Object[] { data });
    }

    private void si_DataReceived(String data)
    {
        textBox1.Text = data.Trim().ToString();
        //textBox1.Text = data;
        //label1.Text = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i read bar code from my bar code reader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621033/how-can-i-read-bar-code-from-my-bar-code-reader)

Comment: Parameters of SerialPort are matching your Windows Device Manager? Sometimes I have set the false baud.

Comment: @c0d3b34n yes I checked them many times and I tried to replace String data = _serialPort.ReadLine(); with String data = _serialPort.ReadByte().ToString(); as you can see.. but that show me  unknow number it shows for example 12 then removed then 26 etc etc

Comment: @PhillipH it is deferent case man he cant read I am telling you that I can read but I am getting error while reading and when I change the Encoding I ma getting unknown characters .. like empty squares  black triangle  or Playing card symbol etc etch

Comment: Ahh, a bit more info on your actual symptoms @useroo1oo :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort spL = (SerialPort) sender;
    byte[] buf = new byte[spL.BytesToRead];
    spL.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    string data = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buf);
}
```

Comment: You can't ignore the number of bytes returned by `Read`, you may get less bytes than you requested back.

Comment: But isn't the quantity of readable bytes defined by SerialPort.BytesToRead Property?

Comment: I would be concerned about internal buffers, if `BytesToRead` was larger than some internal stream buffer inside `SerialPort` the Read may only read one buffer's worth. I may be wrong, but I would not risk it in my production code. Because I did not know for sure if it will happen I only commented instead of downvoting and commenting.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain then what you advice me to do ?

Comment: The normal way is to have a while loop that keeps calling `Read` till all bytes are read in that you are expecting.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain please would you mind to give me an example or a link for example ? a good one please